# execute command in child window viewmodel and pass parameter to function in parent window viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am writing a WPF application with MVVM design pattern. I am facing problem with the execution of command between parent and child windows. The child window is a search window and on click of button, it should execute the search function in the main window. 
    Now, how do I pass the parameter to the parent window viewmodel search function on click of search button on the child window ?
Kindly, help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some sort of messaging service in your system.

Take a look at the following:

- [Prism EventAggregator Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample)
- [Thinking in MVVMLight Messenger](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696340/Thinking-in-MVVMLight-Messenger)
- [Rx as Event Aggergator](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rx%20for%20messaging%20&oq=rx%20for%20messaging%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2324j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=rx%20to%20replace%20eventaggergator)

Or you can implement your own, but I would suggest using one of the available ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action delegate for this.I have developed sample application for your problem and uploaded into Microsoft. Please go through it.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPF-Child-Window-with-MVVM-f8e32d3e